# Cannot connect Android device via USB

Tags: notifications, usb

Whenever I connect my note 3 sm-n900 to my laptop, it doesn't connect and also the usb icon doesn't appear on my notification panel.  My Android version is 5.0

Answer (score 0):

i have experienced the same problem in the past. Here is my Guide:

Navigate to *Settings* > About Phone > scroll to the bottom > tap Build number seven (7) times. You'll get a short pop-up in the lower area of your display saying that you're now a developer. 2. Go back and now access the Developer options menu, check '*USB debugging*' and click OK on the prompt.

Good luck and i hope i'm helpfull

Comment: Can you explain why your answer would work? It definitely didn't, in my device and doesn't make sense either, but I'm not voting it for now until you at least give a solid reason.

Answer (score 0):

do you have installed drivers?
you can find it here http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201410/20141017131240597/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe
also is your phone charing when is connected?
try to install drivers,restart phone(reboot) and connect it.
If that dont work try to use other usb cabble